# 404 errors with wordpress password protected directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My all wordpress pages suddenly start to show a 404 error which can be fixed by going to settings->permalinks and saving to re-create the htaccess files. However, within minuets the admin area is inaccessible giving a "too many redirects" issue. The only way to access the admin area is to delete the .htaccess file via ftp. This was not happening until I have set password protected directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main .htaccess file for WordPress add at the top the following code to fix the redirect loop error:

ErrorDocument 401 default

In your admin .htaccess file for WordPress  add the following code to ensure that front end Ajax continues to work:

```
<Files admin-ajax.php>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy any
</Files>
```